# Validating HTTP request to check if contains all the required fields

Tags: validation, http, go, struct

I am using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) for creating a http server. I want to validate each and every HTTP request before I start calling my other functions.

I created a following `struct` named `CreateUser` to validate all incoming HTTP POST requests for `CreateUser`

```
type CreateUser struct {
   FirstName string `validate:"min:2, regexp=^[a-zA-Z]*$"`
   LastName  string `validate:"min:2, regexp=^[a-zA-Z]*$"`
   Email     string `validate:"min:10, max=255 regexp=^[0-9a-zA-Z]*@[a-z]*$"`
}
```

The following function gets called when a request for `UserCreate` happens. But even if I do not send the `firstName` in the post request. The validation passes without an error. What could be the reason for this? How could I validate each and every HTTP request for it schema?

```
func (uhc UserHttpController) UserCreate(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var createUser config.CreateUser
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&createUser); err != nil {
        // send the bad request response
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    createdUser := InitUserController(uhc.globalVars).UserCreate(createUser)
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "data": createdUser,
    })
}
```

I tried without sending `lastName` in POST request body but on debugging the `LastName` is initialized to `""` empty string and thus no error occurs.

Comment: Use `required` in the validate tag, or the binding tag, as in many of the examples in gin's readme https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin

Comment: The `validate` tag isn't mentioned anywhere in the readme. Is this even using Gin's validation? It uses a completely different set of tags, according to the readme.